# jquery td content by attribute - cannot use children or find methods?

Tags: jquery, find, children

i can't figure out what should be a simple task:

http://jsfiddle.net/elen/7agUc/3/

```
$(document).on("change",'td[col=cat_id] select',function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent(); // getting parent row

    var tr_id = tr.attr('primary_key');
    var d = tr.childern('td[col=Artist').html(); // getting text in the specific cell of the same row

    alert(d);

});​
```

the above code throw an error - "children method is not supported"

the following works:

```
var d = $("tr[primary_key="+tr_id +"] td[col=Artist]").text();
```

but why can't i just use `children()` or `find()` :

```
var d = tr.find('td[col=Artist').text();
```

or am i missing something here?...

Comment: The `find()` method doesn't work because the selector is missing a closing `]`.

Comment: `td[col=cat_id] select` should be `td[col="cat_id"] select`

Comment: @Juhana , of course!! how stupid...

Comment: @Juhana if you add your answer, i accept it as you were first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo: replace `childern` by `children`.

Comment: +1 Also missing a closing `]` on `tr.find('td[col=Artist').text();`

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: @Wesley Murch: just voted to close.

Comment: FYI You keep your rep for posts over 60 days with score 3+ if they get deleted. I'll give you my vote on this one for your help, thanks!

Comment: @Wesley Murch: thanks to you :)

Answer (score 3):

Fix the following line:

```
var d = tr.childern('td[col=Artist').html();
```

To:

```
var d = tr.children('td[col=Artist]').html();
```

[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/7agUc/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a ] in the selector, plus you spelled children wrong. Try using:

```
 tr.children('td[col=Artist]').html()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this-->

```
$(document).on("change",'td[col=cat_id] select',function() {
    var v = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

    var tr_id = tr.attr('primary_key');
    var d = tr.find('td[col=Artist]').html();

    alert(d);

});​
```